# Displaying column values only if criteria is met | mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a columns called `Column1` and `Date_Column1` and `Date_Column2` in a table called `Example1`:

If `Column1` says "Yes" `Date_Column1` can display its value but `Date_Column2` should show nothing

If `Column1` says "Maybe" `Date_Column2` should show its value, but `Date_Column1` should show nothing

How can this kind of conditional be written. Should cases be used in the `SELECT` query?

[image: Expected Results]

Comment: Add sample data, expected result and what you have tried

Comment: Sorry, I just posted the expected result and updated the logic. Please have another look.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

### Use `IF`:

```
SELECT IF(Column1 = "Yes", Date_Column1, "") AS Date_Column1,
       IF(Column1 = "Maybe", Date_Column2, "") AS Date_Column2, 
FROM sometable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `UNION ALL` for 2 queries for each case:

```
select Column1, Date_Column1, null Date_Column2
from tablename
where Column1 = 'Yes'
union all
select Column1, null, Date_Column2
from tablename
where Column1 = 'Maybe'
```